How to set Bengla SutonnyMJ font in JTextArea in Java Swing?
"In my Java Swing project, I have a JTextArea which is jafAddress. In this JTextArea field, I set the font to SutonnyMJ Bangla font. However, when I write Bangla text into the JTextArea, Bangla words are not displayed properly. Only the upper side of the words is visible, Where the lower half is missing. You can see the issue in the image.Word are not showing properly:

But In The JTextFeild SutonnyMJ working perfectly.
        banglaFont = new Font("SutonnyMJ", Font.PLAIN, 20);
        tfAddress = new JTextArea();
        tfAddress.setLineWrap(true);  
        tfAddress.setWrapStyleWord(true);  
        tfAddress.setBorder(customBorder);
        tfAddress.setFont(banglaFont);


        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tfAddress);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setBounds(1025, 300, 250, 100);
        add(scrollPane);

JTextArea wiil showing Bangla SutonnyMJ font Perfectly. Example : ”কামাল”

Set the width in columns and the height in rows when you instantiate the JTextArea and see if that helps.  Use Swing layout managers rather than a null layout.
